# authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch in apache radius authentication

Tags: authentication, apache2, radius

I am trying to implement mod_auth_radius in one of my directory in localhost. I have installed and enabled that module. Added those following line in the end of  my "/etc/apache2/apache.conf" file.

```
AddRadiusAuth 223.27.112.18:1812 idea 5
AddRadiusCookieValid 60
```

.htaccess file in that directory has those lines.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "AdminseHow Radius Authentication"
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthBasicProvider radius
AuthRadiusAuthoritative on
AuthRadiusActive On
Require valid-user
```

But each time I want to login I failed. I have the following error in my error log.

```
[Thu Jun 20 12:11:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] user mehedi: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Thu Jun 20 12:18:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] user mehedi: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Thu Jun 20 12:20:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] user 1778: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Thu Jun 20 12:35:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] user mehedi: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Thu Jun 20 13:02:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] user mehedi: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Thu Jun 20 13:02:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] user mehedi: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have not dug very deeply into this, but I have observed the `Password Mismatch` error (it's actually error # AH01617 ) when the method of encoding a password does not match how the password is encoded on the end authenticating system.

In your case, Apache will solicit, using `AuthType Basic`, a password in **plain text** with [Basic Authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html).

I was not able to locate documentation on the `AddRadiusAuth` directive that you use, but if you specify that the `idea` encryption algorithm is used on your **Radius** authenticating server, then this definitely does not match how the passwords were originally solicited to be sent (Basic Auth).

I will not put money on this since I can't find documentation for `AddRadiusAuth`, but it looks like you can also specify `sharedsecret` other than `idea` according to  [this third party](https://www.wikidsystems.com/support/wikid-support-center/how-to/how-to-add-two-factor-authentication-to-apache) site. But that would also have to be how your **Radius** server is set up as well, which you would factor into this.